# Why does the file fail to log?

Tags: java, file, io

I'm trying to test classes of their writing speed, and I want to log it in a file. I've tried using multiple Writer classes, but it doesn't work. There isn't an error, it just only records the last line. My Code (already tried adding 500ms delay)

```
package writes;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class WriteThread {

    public static final File demoFile = new File("C:\\Java Projects\\FileTests\\demoFile.txt");
    public static final File logFile = new File("C:\\Java Projects\\FileTests\\logFile.txt");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("------FileTests------");
        System.out.println("Demo File for testing is now " + demoFile.length() + " bytes, " + ((double) demoFile.length() / (double) 1000000) + " megabytes.");
        byte[] bytesFor1 = new byte[100000000];
        Arrays.fill(bytesFor1, (byte) 1);
        writeByteArrayFilesWrite(bytesFor1, 100);
        char[] chars = new char[1024];
        Arrays.fill(chars, 'a');
        String line = Arrays.toString(chars);
        writeSingleStringFilesWriteString(line, 0.001);
        char[] chars2 = new char[1000 * 1024];
        Arrays.fill(chars2, 'A');
        String line2 = Arrays.toString(chars2);
        writeSingleStringFilesWriteString(line2, 1);
        List<String> lines = new LinkedList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            lines.add(line2);
        }
        System.out.println("------Using LinkedList------");
        writeStringListFilesWrite(lines, 1, 100);
        List<String> lines2 = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            lines2.add(line2);
        }
        System.out.println("------Using ArrayList------");
        writeStringListFilesWrite(lines2, 1, 100);
        Stream<String> stream = lines.stream();
        Stream<String> stream1 = lines.stream();
        Stream<String> stream2 = lines.stream();
        Stream<String> stream3 = lines.stream();
        Stream<String> stream4 = lines.stream();
        writeStringStreamFilesWrite(stream, stream1, stream2, stream3, stream4, 1, 100);
        writeByteArrayFileOutputStream(bytesFor1, 100);
        writeBinaryByteArrayNIOOutputStream(bytesFor1, 100);
        writeByteArrayBufferedOutputStream(bytesFor1, 100);
        writeStringNoWrap(line2, 1);
        writeStringFileWriter(line2, 1);
        writeStringPrintWriterFileWriterWrap(line2, 1);
        writeStringBufferedWriter(line2, 1);
        writeStringBufferedWriterNIO(line2, 1);
    }

    public static void writeByteArrayFilesWrite(byte[] bytes, double mb) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("------Write Byte Array (" + mb + " MB) to file using Files.write()------");
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Files.write(Path.of(demoFile.getName()), bytes);
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long timeElapsed = (endTime - startTime);
            double timeElapsedS = ((double) timeElapsed) / (double) 1000;
            String msg = "Iteration " + i + ": Write Byte Array (" + mb + " MB) to file using Files.write()," + " took " + timeElapsed + " ms. (" + timeElapsedS + " s)";
            System.out.println(msg);
            log(msg);
        }
    }

    public static void writeSingleStringFilesWriteString(String line, double mb) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("------Write Single String to file using Files.writeString(), " + mb + " MB per string------");
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Files.writeString(Path.of(demoFile.getName()), line);
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long timeElapsed = (endTime - startTime);
            double timeElapsedS = ((double) timeElapsed) / (double) 1000;
            String msg = "Iteration " + i + ": Write Single String (" + mb + " MB) to file using Files.write()," + " took " + timeElapsed + " ms. (" + timeElapsedS + " s)";
            System.out.println(msg);
            log(msg);
        }
    }

    public static void writeStringListFilesWrite(List<String> lines, double mbPer, double mbTotal) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("------Write String List to file using Files.write(), " + mbPer + " MB per string, " + mbTotal + " MB total------");
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Files.write(Path.of(demoFile.getName()), lines);
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long timeElapsed = (endTime - startTime);
            double timeElapsedS = ((double) timeElapsed) / (double) 1000;
            String msg = "Iteration " + i + ": Write list of " + lines.size() + " strings " +
                    "(" + mbPer + " MB per, " + mbTotal + " MB total) to file using Files.write()," + " took " + timeElapsed + " ms. (" + timeElapsedS + " s)";
            System.out.println(msg);
            log(msg);
        }
    }

    public static void writeStringStreamFilesWrite(Stream<String> stream, Stream<String> stream2, Stream<String> stream3, Stream<String> stream4, Stream<String> stream5,
                                                   double mbPer, double mbTotal) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("------Write String Stream to File using Files.write(), " + mbPer + " MB per string, " + mbTotal + " MB total------");
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
//            long count = stream.count();
            long count = 100;
            switch (i) {
                case 1:
                    Files.write(Path.of(demoFile.getName()), (Iterable<String>) stream::iterator);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Files.write(Path.of(demoFile.getName()), (Iterable<String>) stream2::iterator);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Files.write(Path.of(demoFile.getName()), (Iterable<String>) stream3::iterator);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Files.write(Path.of(demoFile.getName()), (Iterable<String>) stream4::iterator);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    Files.write(Path.of(demoFile.getName()), (Iterable<String>) stream5::iterator);
                    break;
            }
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long timeElapsed = (endTime - startTime);
            double timeElapsedS = ((double) timeElapsed) / (double) 1000;
            String msg = "Iteration " + i + ": Write stream of " + count + " strings " +
                    "(" + mbPer + " MB per, " + mbTotal + " MB total) to file using Files.write()," + " took " + timeElapsed + " ms. (" + timeElapsedS + " s)";
            System.out.println(msg);
            log(msg);
        }
    }

    public static void writeByteArrayFileOutputStream(byte[] bytes, double mb) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("------Write Byte Array (" + mb + " MB) file using FileOutputStream.write()------");
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            new FileOutputStream(demoFile).write(bytes);
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long timeElapsed = (endTime - startTime);
            double timeElapsedS = ((double) timeElapsed) / (double) 1000;
            String msg = "Iteration " + i + ": Write byte array (" + mb + " MB) to file using Files.write()," + " took " + timeElapsed + " ms. (" + timeElapsedS + " s)";
            System.out.println(msg);
            log(msg);
        }
    }

    public static void writeBinaryByteArrayNIOOutputStream(byte[] bytes, double mb) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("------Write Byte Array (" + mb + " MB) file using OutputStream.write()------");
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(Path.of(demoFile.getName()));
            out.write(bytes);
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long timeElapsed = (endTime - startTime);
            double timeElapsedS = ((double) timeElapsed) / (double) 1000;
            String msg = "Iteration " + i + ": Write byte array (" + mb + " MB) to file using OutputStream.write()," + " took " + timeElapsed + " ms. (" + timeElapsedS + " s)";
            System.out.println(msg);
            log(msg);
        }
    }

    public static void writeByteArrayBufferedOutputStream(byte[] bytes, double mb) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("------Write Byte Array (" + mb + " MB) file using BufferedOutputStream.write()------");
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(demoFile)).write(bytes);
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long timeElapsed = (endTime - startTime);
            double timeElapsedS = ((double) timeElapsed) / (double) 1000;
            String msg = "Iteration " + i + ": Write byte array (" + mb + " MB) " +
                    "to file using BufferedOutputStream.write()," + " took " + timeElapsed + " ms. (" + timeElapsedS + " s)";
            System.out.println(msg);
            log(msg);
        }
    }

    public static void writeStringNoWrap(String line, double mb) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("------Write String line (" + mb + " MB) file using OutputStreamWriter.write()------");
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(demoFile)).write(line);
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long timeElapsed = (endTime - startTime);
            double timeElapsedS = ((double) timeElapsed) / (double) 1000;
            String msg = "Iteration " + i + ": Write String Line (" + mb + " MB) " +
                    "to file using OutputStreamWriter.write()," + " took " + timeElapsed + " ms. (" + timeElapsedS + " s)";
            System.out.println(msg);
            log(msg);
        }
    }

    public static void writeStringFileWriter(String line, double mb) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("------Write String line (" + mb + " MB) file using FileWriter.write()------");
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            new FileWriter(demoFile).write(line);
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long timeElapsed = (endTime - startTime);
            double timeElapsedS = ((double) timeElapsed) / (double) 1000;
            String msg = "Iteration " + i + ": Write String Line (" + mb + " MB) " +
                    "to file using FileWriter.write()," + " took " + timeElapsed + " ms. (" + timeElapsedS + " s)";
            System.out.println(msg);
            log(msg);
        }
    }

    public static void writeStringPrintWriterFileWriterWrap(String line, double mb) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("------Write String line (" + mb + " MB) file using PrintWriter.write()------");
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(demoFile), false);
            writer.write(line);
            writer.flush();
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long timeElapsed = (endTime - startTime);
            double timeElapsedS = ((double) timeElapsed) / (double) 1000;
            String msg = "Iteration " + i + ": Write String Line (" + mb + " MB) " +
                    "to file using PrintWriter.write()," + " took " + timeElapsed + " ms. (" + timeElapsedS + " s)";
            System.out.println(msg);
            log(msg);
        }
    }

    public static void writeStringBufferedWriter(String line, double mb) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("------Write String line (" + mb + " MB) file using BufferedWriter.write()------");
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(demoFile));
            writer.write(line);
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long timeElapsed = (endTime - startTime);
            double timeElapsedS = ((double) timeElapsed) / (double) 1000;
            String msg = "Iteration " + i + ": Write String Line (" + mb + " MB) " +
                    "to file using BufferedWriter.write()," + " took " + timeElapsed + " ms. (" + timeElapsedS + " s)";
            System.out.println(msg);
            log(msg);
        }
    }

    public static void writeStringBufferedWriterLog(String line) throws IOException {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(logFile), false);
        writer.write(line);
        writer.flush();
        System.out.println("Logged: " + line);
    }

    public static void writeStringBufferedWriterNIO(String line, double mb) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("------Write String line (" + mb + " MB) file using BufferedWriter.write()------");
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Path.of(demoFile.getName()));
            writer.write(line);
            writer.write(line);
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long timeElapsed = (endTime - startTime);
            double timeElapsedS = ((double) timeElapsed) / (double) 1000;
            String msg = "Iteration " + i + ": Write String Line (" + mb + " MB) " +
                    "to file using BufferedWriter.write()," + " took " + timeElapsed + " ms. (" + timeElapsedS + " s)";
            System.out.println(msg);
            log(msg);
        }
    }

    private static void log(String msg) throws IOException {
        writeStringBufferedWriterLog(msg);
    }
}
```

And I am also unsure on how to measure it, I just want to test it on my machine, not real statistics.

Comment: You’re reopening the file every line in truncate mode. Just use a logging framework - this current attempt is both broken and horrendously slow.

Comment: Note, the type of file system location you use has absolutely no bearing on performance - i.e `File` vs `Path`. Further you’re using a lot of buffered writers and not closing them - likely you’re not actually writing anything in your benchmarks.